# How do I write a macro to repeat something up to a specific address?

Tags: assembly, macros, gnu-assembler

[The `.org` directive](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Org.html) advances the location counter to a specified offset, and fills the extra bytes with a specified value.

```
.org 123, 1 @ Pads 1s until we reach address 123.
```

I want to write a macro to do something similar, but with a more complex "fill." Like:

```
@ Pads some_special_symbol until we reach address new_lc.
.macro my_pad new_lc
.if . < \new_lc
    .4byte some_special_symbol
    my_pad \new_lc
.endif
.endm
```

GAS complains about this implementation because [the .if directive requires an absolute expression](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/If.html), and [the dot symbol](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dot.htm) is apparently not absolute.

```
<instantiation>:2:5: error: expected absolute expression
.if . < 10
    ^
```

The only workaround I've found so far is to change the interface of the macro to take a repeat count, instead of an end address. Is there a better way?

Comment: [.fill can take a 4 byte constant too](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Fill.html) But maybe that has the same problem as the `.if`. EDIT: yeah it does.

Comment: Take the distance between `.` and some symbol.

Comment: @fuz Do you have a complete example?

Comment: @Maxpm Too lazy right now to write one.  Basically, if two symbols are in the same section, their difference is a constant and can be used for this purpose.  Place one symbol at the beginning of the section with the other one being `.`.  Note that this only allows you to find the difference from the start of the section in this file, which may not be the overall start after linking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [comment of @fuz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022779/how-do-i-write-a-macro-to-repeat-something-up-to-a-specific-address#comment104290810_59022779)

```
.macro my_pad new_lc
.if . - base < \new_lc
    .4byte 0xdeadbeef
    my_pad \new_lc
.endif
.endm

.data
base:
my_pad 100
```

For a constant the macro can also be implemented using `.fill \new_lc-(.-base), 4, 0xdeadbeef` without recursion.